# How to print collisions in real time on the OMNet ++ console?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am doing the geographic routing in VEINS. However, in a moment the message is not transmitted by a node.

I suspect this is caused by a collision. I know that it is possible to take collision statistics at the end of the simulation.

But, I was wondering if there is any method I can use to print the collision on the OMNeT ++ console in real time.

Development environment used: SUMO 1.2.0, VEINS 5.0 and OMNet++ 5.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at the various visualizers in INET. For example you can set up a packet drop visualizer. See the [related showcase](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/showcases/visualizer/packetdrop/doc).
You can also visualize the actual electromagnetic signal if you want to see it on [lower level](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/showcases/visualizer/spectrum/doc).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Rudi. Would I be able to do this analysis without using INET? In my simulation I use only the VEINS framework.

Comment: You can use macros like EV_TRACE in the C++ code to write things to the log window (when running the GUI version of your simulation) or to the console (when running the command line version). In fact, an EV_TRACE macro already does this [at the place where collisions are counted](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.0/src/veins/modules/phy/Decider80211p.cc#L160), so simply running your simulation in debug mode (and making sure that log messages up to and including `trace` are printed) is enough to achieve what you asked for.